# Е и Ё в фамилии Алехин Алёхин в официальных документах

Tags: е-или-ё

Скажите как будет произноситься фамилия Алехин в документах например в паспорте записанная через букву Е по закону и правилам действующим сейчас на 2019 год Если через Ё то понятно однозначно произносят Ё а если через Е? То будет произноситься АлЕхин через Е? Или может быть два варианта произношения с Е и с Ё?Ведь существует параллельная фамилия АлЕхин так и звучит Е

Comment: Смажьте вашу клаву: она все тчк и зпт красит белым.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос **произношения** фамилий правилами русского языка не регулируется.
Носитель вправе настаивать на том варианте, который считает верным, если это не противоречит базовым правилам чтения.

Что до известных носителей, то большинство их, включая великого шахматиста Александра Алехина, предпочитает произношение без Ё.

Comment: По-русски-то всё-таки без К.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - спасибо. ))) Но вообще забавно, это не потому, что "по-русски", это просто пальцы уже не те, между клавиш попадают.

Comment: Ну понятно, а я не знал, что думать: специально или описка.))

Comment: Любопытно, что шахматисты между собой говорят "Алёхин" (во всяком случае так было ещё когда я занимался шахматами, иное негласно считалось излишним педантизмом, "пижонством"), хотя в современных книгах и википедии это объявлено "распространённой ошибкой". Известно, что на произношении Е настаивал сам Алёхин (кажется, об этом было в его биографии, написанной Котовым), подобно тому как Чебышев (по личному пожеланию) произносился через "-ов" (об этом пишут, но в устной речи этому не следуют, тем более в написании).

Comment: @Alex_ander с обоими - отдельная песня. Массовость не критерий правильности.  Шахматисты тут даже не показатель, а вот в математике - дурдом полный. Произносить Чебышёв как фамилию все уже более или менее согласны. А вот заставить переучить термин (типа "функция Чебышева") - уже никак.

Comment: Возможно, _со стороны_ произносить через Ё удобнее (менее напряжённо, поскольку связывается со словом "Алёха" и запоминается, отсюда массовость), а носителей фамилии можно понять: через Е звучит более "породисто", не по-простецки.

Comment: @Alex_ander А "напряженно" - это как? Тут, имхо, вся напряженность - именно в привычке. Алёха" - это во-первых, а во-вторых, общее правило, что после мягких согласных перед твердыми Е переходит в Ё. все исключения и оговорки, коим несть числа, просто выпадают из рассмотрения в момент произношения. Но главное - это все-таки традиция. Каждый, кто услышал фамилию впервые усвоит её именно так, как услыщал. Да и Алёхины ведь тоже есть среди носителей...

Comment: При отсутствии точек или инструкции по прочтению любой прочитает такую фамилию в предположении, что она образована от знакомого слова (это не совсем "Фонарь" или "Столяр" - в таких фамилиях обычно сдвигается ударение). Если выяснится, что её надо читать иначе, потребуется некоторое усилие (в этом смысле "напряжение") по прочтению менее осмысленного набора букв.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Все это конечно очень интересно... Но давайте к тееме вернемся. Если есть ко мне вопросы конкретно по моему ответу - давайте. А бесконечно рассуждать *ниачом* смысла не вижу.